# Allow Cors with .htaccess file on apache webserver

Tags: apache, webserver

Can I use a .htaccess file on my folder where I upload my file to my website, to allow cors? I try to use this code here in my .htaccess file:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

But this don‘t work. Do I have to add something or do something else?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines in your .htaccess file will solve your problem.

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

You can also resolve cross origin from the index.php file itself. So, there you don't need to make changes in .htaccess file. Try the following code in your index file.

```
// Allow from any origin
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    // should do a check here to match $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] to a whitelist of safe domains
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');
}
// Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");         

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

}
```

Comment: If you are not having php try with the first one. It will work

Comment: I create a file with the name `.htaccess` and copy your first code in. Then I upload this file into the folder, where I've got my file which I want to read. In my js code, I've got this:
`<script type="text/javascript">
                window.onload = function() {
                    fetch("http:145.145.145.12:8800/daten.json")
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => console.log(data));
                };` 
And now I get the error: 
`GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/145.145.135.12:8800/daten.json 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: I don't know why there's my localhost